# Polymer fitInto paper-dialog show on top of drawer

Tags: javascript, dialog, polymer

Just want to fit my paper-dialog inside the 'content' div of the starter kit polymer that it does not show on top of the drawer.

```
<paper-dialog opened modal fit-into="{{content}}">MY DIALOG</paper-dialog>
```

I try

```
ready: function() {
     this.content = Polymer.Base.$$('#content'); \\ null
}
```

and

```
Polymer.Base.$$('body').querySelector('#content')  \\ null
Polymer.Base.$$('body').getElementById('#content') \\ null
document.getElementById("#content")
```

I  do not find a way to retrieve div from outside the shadow dom. It always return undefined or null. I only succeed to retrieve the body.

The content stand on the index.html which contain my custom element

```
<body> 
   ...
   <div id="content">
```

**UPDATE:**

After Kable answer the dialog fit nicely into my content div but the overlay of the modal still cover the whole page, on top of the drawer.  I guess I can solve this by putting some z-index here and there but I wish to constraint the overlay to fit only into the container div?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't really need to use `Polymer.Base.$$('body')` to select the body, you could just use `document.body`.

Secondly, it's possible that the `#content` div isn't available when `ready` is called on your component. Try accessing it inside the `attached` function instead:

```
attached: function () {
    document.body.querySelector("#content");
}
```

If that still doesn't work try wrapping it in an `async` call:

```
attached: function () {
    this.async(function () {
        document.body.querySelector("#content");
    });
}
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-timing-for-siblings for why the `async` call may be necessary.

Comment: attached: work fine, I thought that "ready" was called after "attached". Now the dialog fit into my content div great! Anyway the modal overlay still fill the whole page so I update my question. Thanks Kable